# Camera calibration with opencv for a group of pictures?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, camera, camera-calibration, calibration

I have a group of images that i want to link with a 3D model. I have the X,Y,Z coordinates of 20/30 points of my 3D model and I was thinking on using OpenCV solvePnP Function to link it with X,Y points of the 2D image. However the function asks for the cameraMatrix which I dont have.
If I calibrate my camera now with the chessboard excercise, will the cameraMatrix obtained work for the photographs that I want to link to the 3D model?

In other words, does the cameraMatrix change for a new set of photographs (with a camera in a new position/height) or is it only dependent on the type of camera used (same for all photographs)?

Sorry for my shallow understanding of the camera calibration.
Thanks!

Comment: "the camera matrix" usually means the intrinsics, and those are unaffected by moving the camera.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this mean that camera instrinsic parameters are the same for the same type of certain camera? For example is there a cameramatrix for all Nikon d3500? or for all cameras of an iphone 8?

Comment: probably, with some individual deviations due to manufacturing or user abuse

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the answer. All clearer now!

Comment: oh, when you talk about "nikon d3500", any camera really, you should expect the whole apparatus to have one set of intrinsics. if you change the lens, or even just focus or zoom, the intrinsics change. same goes for phone cameras, webcams, ... some of those operations can be modeled and the intrinsics calculated accordingly.